# c - mixing assignment and free() in a condition?

Tags: c

```
typedef char* string;
int func1(string s);
char* func2(); // returns a new memory/

if(func1(func2()) == 4)
{
// code
}
```

Assuming func2() is only needed in the condition. Since i need to free newly allocated memory, how can i free it up within the same line(i.e. with the same condition or paranthesis) ? My motiviton for this is to keep the code clean.

EDIT 1. 
Yes it is a c question. The use of "string" type was error on my part as i have always typedef it to char*. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Don't do it. Don't put any complex task inside an if condition. It hurts clarity, readability and maintainability.

Comment: this is by no means 'clean'. A rule of thumb is that when a function allocates memory and returns a pointer, the calling context should be responsible for deallocation, meaning keeping the pointer as a variable. And is the `string` type a char * typedef ?

Comment: Calling a function that allocates memory like this is never clean. If you are using C++ (as your use of `string` suggests), do something like `char* temp = func2(); std::string temp2(temp); free(temp);` and use `temp2` in the `if`.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I disagree. Declaring another temp var (as suggested by @filmor) will just complicate the whole code. Always will be wondering how and where the temp var is used. So at least to me it looks cleaner.

Comment: @ato Of course there is _some_ room for opinions. I tend to apply a rule strictly: never do _anything_ complex inside a condition, loop increment expression, etc. This creates more local variables, yes, but it works for me. I understand other people may prefer a different style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free it in the same line with no new function definitions:

```
int result;
char *temp;
/* comma operator: evaluate these 4 expressions left-to-right,
   and the value is the value of the last expression */
if(temp = func2(), result = (func1(temp) == 4), free(temp), result)
{
    /* Do things */
}
```

Cleaner code:

```
int func3(void)
{
    char *temp;
    int result;
    temp = func2();
    result = func1(temp);
    free(temp);
    return result;
}

/* ... */

if(func3() == 4)
{
    /* do things */
}
```

Comment: I am deducing in if(stmnt,..,int_var), only int_var will decide the result of the condition. Is this also true for int conditon_status = (stmnt,..,int_var); . Please confirm both.

Comment: @ato Correct. The comma operator allows you to create expressions in which all comma-separated expressions are evaluated and the value of the overall expression is the value of the last comma-separated expression.

Answer (score 8):

To do this cleanly, make a new function that does the work in a clear manner:

```
static int func3()
{
   char *s = func2();
   int result = func1(s);
   free(s);
   return result;
}

…
if (func3() == 4)
    …
```

(Presumably, there is some assurance that `func2` successfully allocates memory. If not, you must test its return value.)

Comment: If there were only few such instances, i would have used this approach.

Comment: I would think that if there were a lot of such instances you would want to use this approach. To encapsulate the issue into one function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a functional approach:

```
int apply_free(int (*f1)(char*), char * (*f2)()) {
    char *s = f2();
    if (s != NULL) {
        int result = f1(s);
        free(s);
        return result;
    }
    else {
        return -1; /* or any meaningful value if f2 returned a NULL pointer */
    }
}

if (apply_free(func1, func2) == 4)
{
    // code
}
```

This assumes your various cases will have the same type signature.